# Не работает flexslider в табах

Tags: javascript, html, slider, tabs

На сайте используется flexslider.
Ссылка на сайт: http://xn----gtbbezeepmxr.xn--p1ai/test/
Проблема в том, что скрипт слайдера не полностью срабатывает в табах. 
Изначально скрытые табы имею размер 0px, и скрипт строит слайдер в эти 0px. Вот код скрипта:

```js
$(function(){
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 170,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
      });

      $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: "#carousel",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
```

само тело слайдера:

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="duplex1">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides slide_1">
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-1-md.jpg" alt="Duplex1"/> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-2-md.jpg" alt="Duplex1"/> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-3-md.jpg" alt="Duplex1" /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-4-md.jpg" alt="Duplex1" /> </li>
                <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-1-sm.jpg" alt="Duplex1" /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-2-sm.jpg" alt="Duplex1"  /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-3-sm.jpg" alt="Duplex1" /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/duplex1-4-sm.jpg" alt="Duplex1"  /> </li>
                <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>                       
          </div>
        </div>
```

Если удалить настройки в скрипте слайдера, то слайдер работает в табах при их переключении. Но без правил выглядит не красиво и нельзя сделать дополнительно карусель.
Подскажите, как можно поправать или по какому действию перезапускать скрипт слайдера?